# Collections in entities - what are your ways to use it properly?

Tags: c#, collections, interface

So, i think that at in big projects at least part of you defining `interface`s in this way:

```
public interface IUser
{
   //some properties
}
public interface IGroup
{
   //some properties
   ICollection<IUser> Users {get;set;}
}
```

then, after implementing this interfaces, you want to call things somewhere in project in that way:

```
var group = new Group(); // or Container.Resolve<IGroup>();
var user  = new user() {name = "john"};
group.Users.Add(user);
```

but this is not possible in any easy way because we can't cast `List<User>` to `ICollection<IUser>` (becase of covariance and contravariance) without losing reference to `Group.Users` property (using `List.Cast<>` is returning new object) so we can't use method like `Add()`. 
The easiest, working way i know is implemeting interface `IGroup` like this:

```
public interface IGroup
{
   IEnumerable<IUser> Users {get;set;}
   Add(IUser user);
   Remove(IUser user);
   //all methods that any normal collection has
}
```

But this solution sucks because we have to implement a lot of redundant methods in every object with any collection multiplied by number of this collections.

I was trying to solve this problem in any clean and nice way, trying to implement my own collections and so on but i cant find any.
What are your ways to do this a bit cleaner? Do you implement `ICollection<IUser>` and doing some smart things or just give up and do `List'?

Comment: One possibility is to use an `abstract class` instead of an `interface`, and then implement the generic code in the abstract class.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm having difficulty imagining this solution.
Ah, do you mean `public abstract User`, `public abstract Group { ICollection<User> {get;set;}}`?

Comment: If the only behavior on `IGroup` is exposing an `ICollection` on which clients can perform unrestricted operations without any additional "group" specific behavior: you don't need it, remove it completely.

Comment: I often just give up and use List or IList...